# SocketException with Unity C# UDP Receive

Tags: c#, sockets, exception, udp

I'm using Unity and I'm trying to listen to UDP packets coming in on a specific port.  In Unity I have an object with a script attached and the script is designed to simply listen and record data coming in off of the UDP packets.  In the script I have my Start function:

```
public void Start() {
    //  Setup listener.
    this.mListener = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 0);

    //  Setup background UDP listener thread.
    this.mReceiveThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReceiveData));
    this.mReceiveThread.IsBackground = true;
    this.mReceiveThread.Start();
}
```

The function setups the IPEndPoint and the receive thread, then starts the receive thread which is defined as:

```
private void ReceiveData() {
    try {
        //  Setup UDP client.
        this.mClient = new UdpClient(30020);
        this.mClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 250;

        //  While thread is still alive.
        while(Thread.CurrentThread.IsAlive) {
            try {
                //  Grab the data.
                byte[] data = this.mClient.Receive(ref this.mListener);

                //  Convert the data.
                /* REDACTED */

                //  Separate out the data.
                /* REDACTED */

                //  Store data in the DataSource.
                /* REDACTED */
            } catch(SocketException e) {
                Debug.Log(e.ToString());
                continue;
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Debug.Log(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

However, when I try to run this I keep getting the following SocketException:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

This code was working for months, and I've never seen this exception before.  It doesn't really make sense to me.  I've tried changing the port but it doesn't seem to have any effect.  I'm not exactly sure what happened, or what changes I made that made it behave this way.  I have not updated Unity since I started this project.  Could my other program not be sending any UDP packets out?  Could a lack of UDP packets be the cause of this?  The frequency that this SocketException appears in my log *is* related to the ReceiveTimeout property...

Comment: Well, I don't see any obvious problem in the code, but try changing the `IPAddress.Loopback` to `IPAddress.Any` when calling the `IPEndPoint` function.

Comment: I think I failed to mentioned that I had tried this before I posted this with no luck.  I, fortunately, solved my issue by changing from using a separate thread to using async callbacks with the UdpClient.

Still, I'm not sure why this code shouldn't work.